# How to select updated data based upon a condition

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how we can achieve the below scenario

I am getting some data every month. For example below, in that if a projectcode is repeating itself than task is to select new row data for which projectcode is repeating in this case it is 1111 and as well as unique project code which is 1112.

Please do let me idea how I can achieve the same

```
Source Table:
ProjectCode Header1 Header2  Header3    Header4
1111       NewYork  Vivek    Khanna     Not Assigned
1112       Autralia Srinivas Rajole     Assigned
1111       NewYork  Parul    Sharma     Assigned

Desired result:
ProjectCode Header1 Header2     Header3 Header4
1112    Autralia    Srinivas    Rajole  Assigned
1111    NewYork     Parul       Sharma  Assigned
```

Comment: Do you want the most recently-entered row for duplicate ProjectCodes?  And is this Mysql or Sql Server?  Can't be both

Comment: First make sure that you tag your database correctly.. MySQL isn't SQL-server.

Comment: Without an auto_increment id or date time it's impossible to determine what record is the first and what record is the second... and you can't trust the database to return records in insert order without a correct ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Or the other way you can do is apply join and filter those where Header4 = "Assigned"

Comment: "based on a condition"..what condition?   What is the logic behind returning Parul for 1111 instead of Vivek?

Comment: Hi Raymond, I can have a auto_increment id column in my source table... in that case how to do this

Comment: @TabAlleman:  I want to write a procedure where I should be able to select the data from source table based upon projectcode condition

Comment: @user2503377   Unclear.  Define "projectcode condition".

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you're looking for, as you haven't specified the condition for returning one row over another for rows with the same project code. You will need to add an auto increment or datetime variable column if you're looking for newest entries. Then try something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM SourceTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM SourceTable GROUP BY ProjectCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated you have a column which auto-increments, you can use `row_number()`.

In this example, we are applying a an order for each ProjectCode based on YourAutoIncrementColumn. The row which has the highest YourAutoIncrementColumn for each ProjectCode will have a number 1.

```
with cte as(
    select
        ProjectCode
        ,Header1
        ,Header2
        ,Header3
        ,Header4
        ,RN = row_number() over (partition by ProjectCode order by YourAutoIncrementColumn desc)
    from
        sourceTable)

select
    ProjectCode
    ,Header1
    ,Header2
    ,Header3
    ,Header4
from
    cte
where
    RN = 1
```